# what is the degree of zero?

Tags: number-theory

What is the degree of zero? For example, x^2 has degree 2 and the number 5 can be represented as 5x^0 so the number 5 has order 0. But what would the degree of zero be? When multiplying, exponents are added, but when multiplying by 0 this is clearly not the case because 0*5x=0. If the exponents were added the degree would have to be one but this is not the case.

Comment: Various conventions for the degree of the zero polynomial have various advantages and disadvantages. For example, for nonzero polynomials, note that if $f$ divides $g$ then $\deg f \le \deg g$. Since every polynomial divides the zero polynomial, this suggests  setting $\deg 0 = +\infty$! But one has to check every statement about degrees case by case for any proposed dimension. For example, no choice for $\deg 0$ will make $\deg f' = (\deg f)-1$ hold for every polynomial $f$ (it fails either for $f=1$ or $f=0$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One may define it to be $-\infty$ (*Jacobson, BAI*), so that $\deg(fg)=\deg f+\deg g$ always holds, using the convention that $n+(-\infty)=-\infty+n=-\infty+(-\infty)=-\infty$ for any natural number $n$. Constants are usually given zero degree.

Comment: One wonders why $-\infty$ was chosen, since $+\infty$ has the same property.

Answer (score 0):

Others define that zero (or any other constant) has no degree at all.

Comment: Non-zero constant polynomials are generally assigned degree $0$.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that too, makes sense.